# guest os cant connect to real internet but can communicate with other guest vm

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox

host OS: windows 10 core i7-10510U

virtualbox version: 6.1.12

guest OS1 (vm1) : ubuntu 16.04 headless server: Network Setting: Adapter 1 attached to Internal Network : Network Setting: Adapter 2 attached to Bridged

guest OS2 (vm2) : ubuntu 16.04 headless server: Network Setting: Adapter 1 attached to Internal Network

Issue: vm1,vm2 can ping between each other, but ***vm1*** cant connect to real internet even though it has one network adapter set as bridged

Expected result: ***vm1*** to be able to connect to real internet and communicate with vm2.

Full disclosure, this is my first time trying such stuff, pardon me if i am unclear in my explanation.

Comment: Do both adapters on vm2 have valid addresses assigned to them?  Does vm2 have a default route that points to the internet?  Does it have DNS configured to resolve internet names correctly?

Comment: vm2 only have 1 adapter, which is the internal network adapter, use for communicating with vm1, which is working as i did a simple ping to vm1 and receive package

Comment: i did a ifconfig on my vm1 and obtain the vp4 address from there, so its a valid addresses?

Comment: by setting a bridged network adapter, i am using my real computer network card (Wi-Fi xx), so does that mean it has a default route that points to the internet?

Comment: and I haven not done a DNS configured to resolve internet names correctly, not sure how to go about doing it

Answer (score 0):

On the host with two interfaces (vm1), you will need to make sure both interfaces have valid addresses.  These will be different for the "internal" network and the "bridged" network.

The bridged network address will need to be valid on your general LAN -- ie. the network the host is connected to.  Once you have this set, you should be able to ping addresses on your general LAN.

In order for vm1 to reach the internet, it will need a valid bridged IP address and netmask.  It will also need a valid default route specified.  And, while not absolutely necessary, you will probably want to point it to a valid DNS server as well.

These settings are going to be specified within the guest OS (vm1).  The host machine is just passing traffic across the bridged interface.

Instructions on how to do these steps are out of scope here, but you should be able to find plenty of resources online.

The answer to your specific question here is that, most likely the bridged interface is not completely configured.  Try the steps listed above and see what progress you make.

Comment: understood, i will try those steps u mention and post back here

Comment: after i apt-get install network manager, and enable network-manager, it works. without changing anything else. this is so weird

Comment: anyone know why??

Comment: Network manager probably configured the bridged interface via DHCP, which would have automatically edited the route and DNS settings.

Comment: ohh that could explain why. Thanks mikem!